# Crear fichero txt a través de script en PHP

Tags: php, html, php7

Estoy intentando guardar el usuario y contraseña a través de PHP. Sé que los valores se leen correctamente del método POST ya que se muestran correctamente a través del echo. He dejado simplemente el nombre del archivo para que se cree en la misma carpeta donde está el código PHP. ¿Alguien sabría decirme en que estoy fallando?

```
<?php

$usuario = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

echo $usuario . PHP_EOL;
echo $pass . PHP_EOL;

if(file_exists("credenciales.txt")){
        $file = fopen("credenciales.txt", "a");
        fwrite($file, '$usuario' . PHP_EOL);
        fwrite($file, '$pass' . PHP_EOL);
        fclose($file);

}else{
    $file = fopen("credenciales.txt", "w");
    fwrite($file, '$usuario' . PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($file, '$pass' . PHP_EOL);
    fclose($file);
}

?>
```

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 0):

El problema son las comillas simples en los `fwrite()`, ponlas dobles o quítalas.

En PHP, entre comillas dobles, se sustituyen las variables por su contenido.

En cambio, con comillas simples, se muestra el nombre de la variable tal cual, no su contenido. Que será lo que estés viendo en tu fichero.